# Change the Name of an array into Object with JavaScript

Tags: arrays, linq, push, rename

I have an object called *PropertiesToView*, and into that object I have another object called "*LandAreaselectedValues*". I need to rename the object"*LandAreaselectedValues*" for "*selectedValues*" but I am not having success. I have tried with a push, Jquery, LINQ, with a for, and so on. I cant find any solution only with JavaScript or jQuery, does anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to rename the actual class?

Comment: No i cant because these collection is returned to my code from sql and c# code behind, and the name of the property is called LandAreaselectedValues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PropertiesToView[0]['SelectedValues'] = PropertiesToView[0]["LandAreaselectedValues"];

delete PropertiesToView[0]["LandAreaselectedValues"];
```